# Responsive 3 column page with sidebars click to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a similar design/approach to this:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/8092b085a68941f6aaa6708685a62b0d/4.2.8/en-US/acc57dbca1ab4a5bac2a352ce8cc52d8.html?q=Amazon

Notice that, when the sidebar << and >> icons are clicked, those sidebars slide out and the topic/content in the center expands to take the freed up space.

They're using AngularJS but I have to do this using html. I can use jquery, vanilla js, and if it makes sense I can try bootstrap (though I'm obviously not very experienced and want to stick to just html and jquery if possible).

Here is what I've come up with so far. Please excuse the awful color scheme - it's just to delineate the divs:

```js
$("#right-sidebar-slider").click(function() {
  $('#right-sidebar-content').hide('slide', {
    direction: 'right'
  }, 300);
  $("#topic-container").animate({
    width: "75%"
  }, {
    duration: 600,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear'
    }
  });
});

$("#left-sidebar-slider").click(function() {
  $('#left-sidebar-content').hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 300);
  $("#topic-container").animate({
    width: "77%"
  }, {
    duration: 600,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#left-sidebar-slider {
  float: left;
  width: 3%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#left-sidebar-content {
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#topic-container {
  float: left;
  min-width: 58%;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right-sidebar-slider {
  float: left;
  width: 3%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#right-sidebar-content {
  float: left;
  width: 17%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .logo {
  background: url("logo-onlinehelp.png") no-repeat;
  width: 60%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.header .search-input {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

footer {
  clear: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vertex.js"></script>
  <script src="dhtml_toc.js"></script>
  <script src="dhtml_search.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_vertex.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- need for slider effect -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header" style="height: 70px; background-color: gray">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="search-input">
      <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="search-input" value="Search available topics..." size="70">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="left-sidebar-content">
    Table of Contents...
  </div>
  <div id="left-sidebar-slider">
    &lt;&lt;
  </div>
  <div id="topic-container">
    Topic here...
  </div>
  <div id="right-sidebar-slider">
    &gt;&gt;
  </div>
  <div id="right-sidebar-content">
    Feedback form here...
  </div>
  <footer>
    This is our footer text.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

So I have two questions:
1. In terms of overall page structure/approach - wHat is the best approach to building something like this?

2. What is the best approach to replicating the sliding divs? I don't need them to animate, though that would be nice. I just need the user to be able to fill the viewport with the center topic div content.

All of the actual content will come from a CMS. This single page I'm creating is just a template that the CMS (a proprietary one) will use to then insert the content, table of contents, etc. into the html.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle (same as inserted in post):
https://jsfiddle.net/mark2741/wq89r0kL/

Comment: If it's just the approach you want to discuss, you can also post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not far off, but I have a couple of suggestions:

1. CSS flexbox instead of floats to setup the three column layout. ([A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))
2. Use CSS transitions instead of javascript to add the sliding effect. ([Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions))
3. Let the click of a button add/remove a class to the sidebar elements, so you do not need to have presentational informasjon in your javascript

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqaGEg

HTML:

```
<button class="sidebar-left-toggle">
  &lt;&lt;
</button>

<button class="sidebar-right-toggle">
  &gt;&gt;
</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">sidebar-left</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">sidebar-right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.sidebar-left, 
.sidebar-right {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.sidebar-collapsed {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  background: #eee;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const leftToggle = document.querySelector('.sidebar-left-toggle');
const rightToggle = document.querySelector('.sidebar-right-toggle');
const leftSidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar-left');
const rightSidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar-right');

leftToggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
  leftSidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar-collapsed');
});

rightToggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
  rightSidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar-collapsed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will look into flexbox. It seems everything I've been trying to do lately points to using it but I was hesitant because of browser support but I think I can get away with not supporting pre IE11.